# App-based language selection for Samsung keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

Is there any solution for the problem in question?

I want to use EN(UK) whenever I use the keyboard in the browser, but I want to use another language whenever Im using the gmail app.

Is it somehow possible to automate?

Comment: try automation apps like tasker, macrodroid, automate